# How to populate struct slice using array?

Tags: arrays, struct, go, slice

In Go is it possible to populate a struct slice? My data is an array of strings.

```
a := [string1, string2, string3, string4]

type User struct {
     NickName string
}

var u []User
```

How do I populate `u` with the contents of `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use make to create the slice and a for loop to populate the slice:

```
u := make([]User, len(a))
for i := range a {
    u[i].NickName = a[i]
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/z6QUDf3cuC)

Comment: Thank you sir, it would have taken me a whole day to figure that out.